# TableView Cell with Minor Lag (Async Proper Use?) Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, asynchronous, swift4

I have an **array full of Data** loading images in a **tableView Cell.** However I am getting minor **lag**(more of a glitch) when the **table view scrolls on image index.**

**Array Contains Data(Seems to lag more bigger the bytes)**

> Data in Bytes(624230 bytes)
>
> Data in Bytes(1619677 bytes)
>
> Data in Bytes(2257181 bytes)
>
> Data in Bytes(1120275bytes)

Not Sure How to properly use Async When the data is loaded.

```
struct messageCellStruct {

    let message: String!
    let photoData: Data!

}

var messageArray = [messageCellStruct]()



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")


        let message2 = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UITextView


        var photoUploadData = messageArray[indexPath.row].photoData

        let main = DispatchQueue.main
        let background = DispatchQueue.global()
        let helper = DispatchQueue(label: "another_thread")



        if(photoUploadData != nil){

            print("Data in Bytes\(String(describing: photoUploadData))")



                    let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
                    let image1Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
                    let newImageWidth = (self.message.bounds.size.width - 20 )
                    let messageDisplayString = self.messageArray[indexPath.row].message

            background.async {
                    image1Attachment.image = UIImage(data: photoUploadData!)
            }


                    image1Attachment.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: newImageWidth, height: 200)


                    let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)


                    fullString.append(image1String)
                    fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: messageDisplayString!))

                    message2.attributedText = fullString
                    message2.textColor = .white
                    message2.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)


        }else {

            message2.text = self.messageArray[indexPath.row].message

        }




        return cell!
    }
```

The reason I introduced the Async in the first place was because of the lag. It lags with and without the Async.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you simply use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to load the images in table cells. `UI` work should never be done in `backgroundQueue`. If you download any data in background then while showing do it `mainQueue`.

Comment: I have Alamofire but I dont know how to integrate SDWebImage or AlamoFire with a NSAttachment. They are great for UIImageViews.

Comment: Also if you perform the download task in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you will have to handle the ongoing requests as this method calls multiple times. If you want to avoid extra headache use any library for this.

Comment: Okay, But why do you need the image in `TextView`? Please mention your requirement as generally no one does this.

Comment: i dont know how to properly implement a imageView and a textView in a organized maner without doing this.

Comment: BTW! You can also perform a simple downloading task using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). It doesn't require an `imageView`. And there is call back function which will let you know that image has been downloaded with or without any error.

Comment: `#1. Label or TextView` ,  `#2. imageViiew or TextView or Label` depends on if editable. Hide `imageView` if there is text and hide `TextView or Label` if there is an image.

Comment: @husharoonie : Take a look at the answer in EDIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never perform any UI operations on background thread.

remove `background.async` from

```
        background.async {
                image1Attachment.image = UIImage(data: photoUploadData!)
        }
```

simply use

```
image1Attachment.image = UIImage(data: photoUploadData!)
```

**EDIT:**

The lag is not because of `UIImage(data: photoUploadData!)` I agree that it is a synchronous call but that wont create a lag the real culprit is `let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)` `NSAttributedString` is known to be notorious.

To test the hypothesis you can comment out

```
                let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)


                fullString.append(image1String)
                fullString.append(NSAttributedString(string: messageDisplayString!))

                message2.attributedText = fullString
                message2.textColor = .white
                message2.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
```

and you should not see a lag.

Unfortunately I don't know the way to fix the issue with `NSAttributedString` we had same issue and it would often add up lag on scrolling huge pile of rows. Hence we decided to opt for [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText)

Somehow this performs better than `NSAttributedString`

**EDIT:**

We concluded that the delay/lag is probably because of conversion of huge data to `NSAttributedString`. As all that OP wanna do is show image and text below it n he did not know how to handle multiple components in cell I am updating the answer to same.

I am not claiming that this is the only way to do it this way might help the OP is assumption here

**Step1:**

Create UITableViewCell xib and drag UIImageView to it.

[image]

Now imageViews can take implicit size. What does that mean is UIImageView's can grow based on the image shows. If the images you are loading happen to be in your control (Server sending images is yours) and if your backend team can assure that they wont send crazy big images you dont need height constraint to ImageView.

But more often than not, server team claims that its a client team job. Because you would like to show the image best possible way and showing image with aspect fit and let the bigger part of image being chopped off or if image happens to be small leaving the huge space around image ask the backend team to send aspect ratio as a part of the response.

So  in that case create a height constraint to imageView

[image]

Create an IBOutlet to the height constraint lets assume you call it as `imageHeightConstraint`

Now when you load the image in cell, you know that imageView's width will be equal to the width of the cell and you know the aspect ratio of the image to be shown so you can calculate the height of supposed image as

either in `cellFroRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.imageHeightConstraint.constant = cell.bounds.size.width * aspectRatioOfImage
```

or better if you have `configure` method in a cell where you would expect cell to configure its subviews then

```
self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.bounds.size.width * aspectRatioOfImage
```

Obviously you might need to convert it to `Float` from `CGFloat` am sure u can do it :)

Now if you dont have any control over image and you are downloading it from some random website and hence dont have aspect ratio info then rather than adding height constraint add aspect ratio constraint to imageView and change imageView content mode to .aspectFit this might have side effects I mentioned above but thats the best you get without any support :)

[image]

Now add TextView below imageView

[image]

add vertical height constraint between imageView and TextView

[image]

Select textView and set scroll enabled as false

[image]

Select TextView and change vertical content hugging priority and compression resistance to 999

[image]

Thats it :)

Now what have you achieved with all these circus is that now you have a TableViewCell which can take implicit size based on content it has without any ambiguity :)

Now that makes the life easy. Implement tableView delegates and dont forget to use

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

Thats it :) Now run your code and enjoy self expanding tableView cells based on the content they show :) And you have the layout u wanted

Hope it helps

Comment: The reason I introduced the Async in the first place was because of the lag. It lags with and without the Async.

Comment: @husharoonie : The lag is not because of `UIImage(data: photoUploadData!)` I agree that it is a synchronous call but that wont create a lag the real culprit is  `let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1Attachment)`  `NSAttributedString` is known to be notorious

Comment: How can I change it? Its more of a glitch when it touches the index not so much loading the actual image.

Comment: @husharoonie : read the updated answer n lemme know if it helps

Comment: The image is displaying through a textview. I need that part the image wont display without it.

Comment: @husharoonie : Why would u show image through textView?? May I see the UI ? Have u considered other alternative components for ur requirement? As far as I know conversion to NSAttributed or NSMutableAttributed string is costly hence adds the lag

Comment: UI in post Update

Comment: @husharoonie : Looking at the out put looks like a UITableView Cell with TextView and UIImageView to me, I understand that using a textView and showing image in it gives u flexibility as u don't need multiple components in cell, u don't need to mess with their sizes and u can provide flowing text around image using TextLayout but that I think comes with the cost of lag, if u have a fixed structure as shown in image above I would rather add UIImageView and TextView to cell and handle them :) Just a thought

Comment: Can you show me how to implement a imageView pragmatically without adding one in the story board to accommodate my situation. Simply above the text of the TextView?

Comment: @husharoonie : Gimme sometime :) Ill post the answer here